# Is it possible to find the numbers user sent SMS to in cocoa touch?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, sms

I'm using below code to send sms. We want to find the numbers user is sending text and give them free credit. I just wonder if it is possible to get the numbers which user sent text to.

```
-(IBAction)promotionSms{
    if(![MFMessageComposeViewController canSendText]) {
        UIAlertView *warningAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Your device doesn't support SMS!" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [warningAlert show];
        return;
    }

    NSString *message = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Text Here"];

    MFMessageComposeViewController *messageController = [[MFMessageComposeViewController alloc] init];
    messageController.messageComposeDelegate = self;
    [messageController setBody:message];

    // Present message view controller on screen
    [self presentViewController:messageController animated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (void)messageComposeViewController:(MFMessageComposeViewController *)controller didFinishWithResult:(MessageComposeResult)result
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

    if (result == MessageComposeResultCancelled)
        NSLog(@"Message cancelled");
    else if (result == MessageComposeResultSent)
        NSLog(@"Message sent");
    else
        NSLog(@"Message failed");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is **no way** to know the number to which user sent the message.

An **Alternative** would be like:

Implement [**ABPeoplePickerNavigationController**](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/ContactData/Conceptual/AddressBookProgrammingGuideforiPhone/Chapters/UI_Controllers.html) for choosing a contact within your application. If they choose a contact present the `MFMessageComposeViewController` with your message and the number (chosen on the `ABPeoplePickerNavigationController`).
In that way you can keep track the number, there is no other way to do that.

In above case also after presenting the `MFMessageComposeViewController`, user can edit the number from there, you can't get the edited number then.

Answer (score 1):

@MidhunMP answer is good, however there's one other way that you may implement.

Create a view which takes user name (if needed) and his phone number, and then on a button tap open `MFMessageComposeViewController` to send the message.

As I can see in your code, you should only give him a credit when message status is `MessageComposeResultSent`.

However, there's always chance of (as Midhun told), that user may change their number in `MFMessageComposeViewController`. The only way to overcome to this is to send SMS by your app only (doesn't matter via some SDKs or via APIs).